# Deploying Rails and React to Heroku fails

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am building a Rails 7 (backend) and React app (frontend) in the same app.
I am trying to deploy it to Heroku but I got an error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript
module script but the server responded with a MIME type of
"text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module
scripts per HTML spec.
```

What does this mean? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same errror in Google Chrome. Inspecting the console in Safari yielded more useful errors.

In my case it highlighted an issue with my imports in app/javascript/application.js. I was importing custom JS files stored in the folder **app/javascript/custom** like this:

```
import "./custom/setTrixToolbar";
import "./custom/embedsController";
```

To solve the problem, I removed the './' element and added the following line to the config/importmap.rb file.

```
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/custom', under: 'custom'
```

This config/importmap.rb file needs to be configured to import all your custom JS.

Without seeing any of your code it's impossible to know if thats the issue, but this may be a start.

The following video is useful in explaining how importmaps in Rails 7 works:

[youtube.com/watch?v=PtxZvFnL2i0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtxZvFnL2i0)